# Need to Check a checkbox based on SQL data in a React Project

Tags: sql, reactjs

This is a React project using a Node, Express, Axios backend. What I am needing to achive is to have a checkbox show as checked if the database is a 1 or unchecked if its a 0 for the Active column. The full project is connected properly and I can pull the data and display properly for everything but the Active column using the below code.

UserList.js file

```
import "./userList.css";
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


class UserList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Collectors: '',
    collectorList: []
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTaskList()
  }
  
  getTaskList = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getCollectors')
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({collectorList: result});
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="userList">
        <h3>Collectors</h3>
            <table className="blueTableHeaders">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Active</th>
                  <td>Collectors</td>
                  <td>Aging Bucket</td>
                  <td>Program Code</td>
                  <td>Finance Company</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
        {this.state.collectorList.map((Collectors) => (
          <div>
            <table className="blueTableData">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><input type="checkbox" name="Active" checked={Collectors.Active === 0 ? 1 : 1}/></th>
                  <th>{Collectors.Active}</th>
                  <td>{Collectors.FirstName} {Collectors.LastName} | {Collectors.CollectorCode}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Link to="/newUser">
          <button className="userListAddButton">Add Collector</button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/deleteUser">
          <button className="userListDeleteButton">Delete Collector</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

Server.js

This is what I am pulling on the server side and as shown and mentioned above I get all the data but the Active.

```
app.get('/getCollectors', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query('SELECT * FROM CollectorAssignment.tCollectorsTest').then(result => {
            res.send(result.recordset)
        })
     })
})
```

The below is what I am trying but this does not base it if the Active column has a 1 or 0 in the SQL it just either checks it or unchecks it currently as I have 2 of the people above as Active and 2 as not active so Kyle and Brian should show as unchecked for the Active column

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="Active" checked={Collectors.Active === 0 ? 1 : 1}/></th>
```

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the issue was that in SQL it is a 1 or 0 but forgot react pulls it in as true or false so after I updated the below it is working properly. I found this by doing a simple {console.log('Active:', Collectors.Active)} to see what the data was actually showing as.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Active" checked={Collectors.Active === false ? false : true}
```